# Blender 3.0 renders only half when in 4k

Tags: rendering

I know there are a lot of threads similar to this, but I did not see one that has the same problem. Everything is fine with render when it is set to 1080p, but when I set it to 4k it renders only half of camera. I tried a lot of different projects and no change, only half renders.

Comment: Also, it will render one half but when it's "done", it will do the other half as well...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the new Cycles X renders the whole image as one, this way you can go to **Render settings > Performance > Tile size**... by default, there is **2048**,
[image]

that means that it renders the image as **2048*2048** tile.... 1920 fits into 2048 so it makes it in 1 tile, but if you use 3840 it requires you to change that 2048 value to a bigger value such as 4096 or 3840 or let it render as 4 tiles

Or you can uncheck **Use Tiling**

Comment: Hi :). That's not how tiling works, it wouldn't be practical. I just rendered in 4K with 1024 tiling and it works as in previous versions.

Comment: Yes because it doesn't work anymore, instead of every core doing one tile, all your resources are doing 1 tile at the time, how does your blender render same as in previous version if they changed basics? Also I already know that rendering whole 4K image as once is faster than tiling it in cycles X, I render a lot of over 4k images at work

Comment: What I meant is - the tilesize doesn't matter, you will always get the specified resolution. Or it doesn't work for you either? :))

Comment: No I don't get the specific resolution by default, if I use 3840x2160 image size and default render settings, it renders 2048*2048 tile first and then 3 smaller tiles that fit the rest of the image resolution

Comment: Exactly. Just as in previous versions. That got me thinking - is the OP just impatient waiting for the 1 tile to finish? Does he think that's all he'll get? :))

Comment: yeah sorry, i probably misunderstood the OP and the answer :) time for a coffee